# How to make the selected title and its content as active and others as inactive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav-pills

I am doing a website for educational institution in which there is schools with sub division as matric, cbse, and state board and also a college.. Here what i need was when we click on matriculation stream, the matric schools need to be in active state and like wise for other streams (cbse,stateboard and college).. Now i have given as pills and mentioned every institutions inside with titles as pills..

The html of what i tried was,

```
<section class="ourscl" id="school">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2 class="hdng"><span class="schools-title">Our Schools</span></h2>
      <h4 class="italic-line"> 100+ schools with world class education </h4>
      <div class="plus_image"><img class="repeat_image"></div>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified navbar-default" style="color:white;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px">
        <li class="active brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a href="#mtrcscl1" data-toggle="pill">Matriculation Stream</a></li>
        <li class="brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#cbse">CBSE Stream</a></li>
        <li class="brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#hgrscl">State Board</a></li>
        <li class="tab-wid font-sz"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#clg">B.Ed College</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px">
        <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade in active" id="mtrcscl1">
          <div class="rooms">
            <h2 class="hide-sec">Matriculation Stream</h2> -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthuraiyur.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdambikaa Boys MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthottiyam.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdaambikaa MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowshivani.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdambikaa MHSS</h4>
                    <p>T.Pettai - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cmhss.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chellammal Boys MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://chelammal.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chelammal MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Crawford - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://akkv.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                    <h4>AKKV MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Annamalai Nagar - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthuraiyur.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdambikaa Girls MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="">
                    <h4>Chellammal MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Nagamangalam - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="">
                    <h4>Chellammal MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Viralimalai - Pudukottai</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cmhss.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chellammal Girls MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="cbse">
                <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="cbse">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="rooms col-sm-3">
                <h2 class="hide-sec">CBSE Stream</h2> -->
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cvcsmusiri.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chelammal Vidhyaashram</h4>
                    <p>Musiri - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="cbse">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cvcbse.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chellammal Vidyalaya</h4>
                    <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="cbse">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://srmschool.edu.in/">
                    <h4>SRM Public</h4>
                    <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="hgrscl">
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="rooms col-sm-3">
              <h2 class="hide-sec">State Board</h2> -->
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="hgrscl">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cmullai.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Mullai HSS</h4>
                    <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="clg">
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="rooms col-sm-3">
              <h2 class="hide-sec">B.Ed College</h2> -->
              <div class="col-sm-3" id="clg">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://shivacollege.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Shiva College of Education</h4>
                    <p>Thathiengarpet - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

And css was,

```
.ourscl .navbar-default{
    background-color:rgb(222, 35, 41) !important; /*rgb(144,21,14)!important;*/
}
.ourscl {
  background: #ffcb05;
}
.nav-pills li.active a{
    background-color: #FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a:focus{
    background-color:#FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover{
    background-color: #FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a {
    color:#fff;
}
.nav-pills li a{
    border-radius:0px!important;
}
.hide-sec{
    display: none;
    text-align: left!important;
}
.nav-pills{
    display: block;
}
 .brdrlt{
     border-left:1px solid #FEC73D!important;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left: 10px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
 }
.tab-wid.active::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    /* top: 50%; */
    /* margin-top: -13px; */
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #FEC73D;
}
.schools-title {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(images/title_white.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.italic-line {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.plus_image {
  background: url(images/plus-sign.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
.brdrlt h4 {
  color: #bc0101
}
.brdrlt p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

The jsfiddle link for what i done was

https://jsfiddle.net/1at91Lgo/ (Better extend the output box to get better view of column split up as like in image)..

And the output which i need is to be like the attached image

[image]

As the image clearly describes my requirement, if i click CBSE stream the schools with cbse streams should get active and others to be inactive.. And my second requirement in it was the selected stream schools should be in top row as like in image. Any help that gives me a better and clear solution would be much more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, you can achieve a similar result with hovers, adding this to your CSS: `.tab-content:hover .col-sm-3:not(:hover) { opacity: .5; }`

However, if you need a click to create a "permanent" state for the links, you should look into a JavaScript solution to toggle a specific class on the container and the active element.